# Combining Text in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have multiple columns that I want to merge together, but I want it driven by a table.  So a user can specify let's say fields: 'A', 'B', 'C' and another use can say they want 'A', 'B', 'E', 'Z', etc...

So I want this to be dynamic in a sense.  In addition between each row value, I need to insert a `\n` value to have a new line character.

So in my field `description`, given the first example, I need the string to be formatted as:

```
'A: ' + df['A'] + "\n" + 'B: ' + df['B'] + '\n' + 'C: ' + df['C'] + '\n'
```

When working with string data in python, you can leverage the `+=` operation to append text to an existing string, so I thought I could create a column called `description` on my Pandas dataframe object and then use the `+=` operation to push everything together.

```
df['description'] = ""
for f in fields:
    df['description'] += f + ": " + df[f] + '\n'
```

But this raises a typeerror:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

I am using Pandas 0.16.1

Thanks

Comment: Does `df['description'] = df['description'] + ...` work? If so, that's what you should use.

Comment: What is your `fields` variable in the line `for f in fields:`?

Comment: Can you provide a larger example?  What comes after the df['description]?

Comment: For me it works perfect, but use `pandas 0.19.1`

Comment: fields = ['A', 'B', 'C']

Comment: Ah, remove the `+=` operator for older versions of pandas.

Comment: The `...` would just be what you already wrote: `df['description'] = df['description'] + f + ": " + df[f] + '\n'`.

Comment: What @3novak wrote, same thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
df['description'] += f + ": " + df[f].str.cat(sep=' ') + '\n'
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP wants.